# SQL - Create a query that returns pairs of values

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have to create a query that returns a pairs of authors (name and surname) that have written a book together.

These are the tables:

**AUTHOR**

```
orcid (PRIMARY KEY to identify AUTHOR)
name
surname
```

**Book**

```
doi (PRIMARY KEY to identify book)
title
```

**WRITES**

```
orcid (foreign key references Orcid (Author)) 
doi (foreign key references Doi (Book))
```

For example

```
BOOK TITLE = RED ROSE (DOI = A100)
WRITTEN BY AUTHORS = X (ORCID = 2 ) AND Y (ORCID = 1)
```

I'm stuck on this problem, this is what I have tried but I don't know how to take only pairs of authors.

```
SELECT author.name, author.surname
FROM author
JOIN writes ON writes.orcid = author.orcid
JOIN book ON writes.doi = book.doi
```

Sorry if I didn't be clear, but English is not my mother tongue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a self-join.  And then more joins:

```
SELECT a1.name, a1.surname, a2.name, a2.surname
FROM writes w1 JOIN
     writes w2
     ON w2.doi = w1.doi JOIN       -- same book
     author a1
     ON a1.orcid = w1.orcid JOIN   -- first author
     author a2
     ON a2.orcid = w2.orcid AND    -- second author
        a2.arcid < a1.arcid        -- keep the pairs in order
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! 
(there is only a little error on the fourth row but nothing of serious (w2.doi = w1.doi it's the join condition), thanks again!